# Parameterless implementation for Ninject mappings

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, ninject, membership-provider

i am creating custom membership provider using ninject for binding to sql classes.

my class in looks like

```
public MyMembershipProvider(IUsersRepository userRepository)
{
   this.userRepository = userRepository;
}
```

How can i create from this parameterless constructor?

Comment: have a look arounbd for other membership provider questions here - this has def been answered in much depth before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
kernel.Bind<IUsersRepository>().To<UsersRepository>();
kernel.Bind<MembershipProvider>().To<MyMembershipProvider>();
```

and then:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private readonly MembershipProvider _membershipProvider;
    public AccountController(MembershipProvider membershipProvider)
    {
        _membershipProvider = membershipProvider;
    }

    public ActionResult Foo()
    {
        // TODO: Use the membership provider to do some processing
        return View();
    }
}
```